# hide hidden folders in tkinter gui

Tags: python, tkinter

How can I hide hidden folders from appearing when `askopenfilename` is used i.e only show regular folders (not hidden)

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
path = filedialog.askopenfilename(title='Please Select File', filetypes=[('Excel files', ('.xlsx'))])
```

Comment: Which platform are you on? Windows?

Comment: On Windows, the visibility of folders/files is dependant on the folder options in windows explorer and not something that can be directly "filtered" in tkinter's askopenfilename dialog.

Comment: @scotty3785 I am on linux (Ubuntu)